# can I mount a file directly in a pod without an intermediary config or secret?

Tags: kubernetes

If I have a bunch of Kubernetes pod definitions all sharing the same image but differing in their environment and a unique script which I mount for each one, I can mount the script by creating a separate ConfigMap for each one, but it seems unnecessarily tedious and obfuscating-- is there a way to mount a file by specifying the contents in the pod yaml definition directly?

Comment: You kubernetes cluster is generally not running in the same place as your local files, so directly mounting them isn't an option. It is relatively easy using a tool like [kustomize](https://kustomize.io) to generate the necessary ConfigMaps. Note that you can include multiple files in single ConfigMap so it doesn't need to be all that tedious.

Comment: @larsks I don't mean mounting a local file-- I mean mounting a file whose content is specified in the pod definition file instead of a ConfigMap.

Comment: With appropriate permissions you can use a [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume.